# How can I varify that I got all isomorpism class of the group's irrduceable representation?

Tags: representation-theory

Let's assume that I want to find the 2-dimetional complex irreduable representations (up to isomorphism) of $ G =  \langle x,y | x^4 = y^3 = 1, yx = xy^2 \rangle $. How can I varify that I there are no more classes?

The question is about to find it without advanced results. Only with material of first-second lecture of elementary representation theory.

Comment: I don't know if you will like it, but it seems that your group is finite. So you compute explicitly the number of conjugacy classes, which gives you a first bound for the number of irrep of dimensions 2. Indeed, there are no more irrep, so if you can compute 1-dim irrep you will get them all.

Comment: Thanks, thats good enough for me.